# Grails Asset Pipeline plugin: using third-party CDNs

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, assets, cdn

How can I easily use third-party CDNs with the [Grails Asset Pipeline plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline)?

Asset Pipeline can redirect all asset requests to single base URL; that works for serving my static files from a server that is not my Grails server, but it requires that all of my static files are on that server.

My proprietary JS & CSS, however, won't ever be on a public CDN.  Also, some of the standard libraries that I use might be hosted by different CDNs, so I'll need to be able to reference multiple different CDNs.

I need to specify a mapping per asset (or asset pattern).

Also, the URLs to assets on public CDNs must include the version of the asset.

I don't want to include the version number in every reference to an asset, so I need to be able to map from the asset name to a complete URL, instead of being restricted to a base URL mapping prepended to an asset name.

I'm using Grails 2.5.0; if the answer is different for Grails 3.x, info about both versions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The aset-pipeline actually allows the base url mapping to be a Closure. This closure takes a single input argument with the request object. You can actually use this to manipulate the base asset url on a request basis. The docs have more about this in the configuration section

Comment: That closure has in a Request argument, so it must run in Grails at runtime, right? All the mapping that I want can logically be done at build time; I don't need runtime dispatch for my usage, and I don't want the overhead. With runtime dispatch, I can't link to Asset Pipelined assets from my static files: e.g., file A references assets B, C & D via Asset Pipeline. B is on a CDN, C is on my static server, and D is on my Grails server. If Asset Pipeline doesn't inject actual URLs for those references at build time, then I can't generate a static A and serve it from my static server.

Comment: Also, it looks like that closure returns a base URL, and can't add a version to the asset name, or modify the URL in any way except via prepending the base URL.

Comment: If Asset Pipeline doesn't support mappings at build time, they could add a new config property, possibly named "grails.assets.build.mapping", that accepts a Closure<String> with one or two String arguments.  At build time, Asset Pipeline would call the Closure whenever attempting to generate a URL for an asset, with the asset's name as the first argument, and the value of grails.assets.url as the second.  The returned String is the full URL to the asset.  Returning null could be a special case, or could cause a build-time NPE.

Comment: what exactly are you referring to as File A here? Are we talking about css, javascript, both? The downside to doing this at build time is your lose portability of your war file potentially. It is now solely dependent on whatever mappings you pointed it to on a CDN. Production runtime mapping overhead can be kept very efficient with a cache map. I suppose I'd have to see an example use case feel free to post on the github and Ill take a look

Comment: I don't yet know if Asset Pipeline supports injecting into HTML files; if so, CDN and other links could be injected into HTML files at build time, and those files could be deployed on a static server.  So, if Asset Pipeline supports it, A could be an HTML file.  If it doesn't support inject into HTML files, I could still imagine using GSPs solely for asset injection (without other logic), with Asset Pipeline converting the GSPs to HTMLs at build, and serving those from the static server